# Reducing HTML Table Row Height

Tags: html, css

I have table with few rows. I want 1st and 3rd row height to be set to 1 px and the 2nd row to normal height. But my code is not working.

[image]
**HTML CODE goes below**

```
<table border="0">
   <tr style="height:2px;" >
    <td width="10"><hr></td>

  </tr>
<tr style="height:20px;" >
    <td width="10">Hello</td>

  </tr>
  <tr style="height:20px;" >
    <td width="10"><hr></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Could anyone please tell me how to do it ?

**Note**: I dont want borders to be used because i Want for certain rows i may or may not need the horizontal line inside the rows.

Comment: Why not use borders instead of a table?

Comment: @myajouri : I may or may not want certain fields to have horizontal line... It should be dynamic

Comment: Give "certain" fields a class name for the border. That's what CSS is for. Mark-up should not be used for styling.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add  `style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"` to your `hr` and change the `height` of your third `tr` to `2px`

You will have :

```
<table border="0">
   <tr style="height:2px;" >
    <td width="10px"><hr style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"></td>
  </tr>
<tr style="height:20px;" >
    <td width="10px">Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:2px;" >
    <td width="10px"><hr style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 10 is not a valid value for the width property - HTML5

Comment: @Dylan Chensky Yes it's a valid value if i'm looking at the example at w3school (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp). But it's really a better idea to write "10px"

Comment: w3schools.com is a bad place to get your information. Use Mozilla.com